# Cant push docker image to local registry by .sh script called from plink - no basic auth credentials

Tags: docker, docker-registry, plink

I have a problem by pushing docker image in the local registry.
I have a local registry for example `some.registry.com`.
My script looks like (`build.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# some commands
# build image
# tag image
docker push some.registry.com/my/imagename
```

This script works fine if I run it from the current system (i run on ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo ./build.sh
```

But I need to invoke this script from another script on a windows machine.
I use for this `plink`
This script looks like (`other_script.bat`):

```
REM do something
call D:\install\plink.exe -ssh -v -t user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -pw PASS "sudo -S <<< 'PASS' /home/user/scr/build.sh"
```

All command in `build.sh` are working fine (build image, tag image e.t.c). But when `docker push` is called I receive a message `no basic auth credentials`

Has someone any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put you credentials in a file locally on your machine? Create json.config file under C:\Users\.docker or on Linux at $HOME/.docker/config.json and copy the following content to that file

```
{
        "auths": {
                "your.registry.com": {
                        "auth": "aGVja2VhOiFoZWNrb25vXXXX"
                }
        } 
}
```

Note that the auth string ist your username password in BASE64 encoded. If you have a random Linux docker host where you have logged in to the registry before you can take the whole json.config file from the home directory there as well.

Sidenote: We had a similar issue with the io.fabric docker-plugin and solved it with the steps described above.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. But may be i don't understand You well enough. I don't have docker on a windows machine. Do I have to use some a credits store or what else? But I think I solve my problem. I added in my script (`build.sh`) before pushing image docker login command : 
`docker login -u user -p pass https://reg.com
 docker push ...`

Comment: Hi, docker login on the host is an option nevertheless. I meant something like you can log into any public or private repository for which you have credentials. When you log in, the command stores encoded credentials in $HOME/.docker/config.json on Linux or %USERPROFILE%/.docker/config.json on Windows.